# Использование БД "HP Vertica" через dbplyr(R) в Win10

Tags: база-данных, r

Поскольку Vertica работает только в Linux, установил Vertica 10-Dev  в виртуальной машине. Как ее можно использовать в Win10 через dbplyr(R)? Перейти полностью в Линукс не вариант. Может у кого то есть опыт в аналогичной ситуации.

Answer (score 0):

Подключиться к Verica можно через ODBC драйвер. Для есть несколько реализаций ODBC: `RODBC`, `RJDBC`, `odbc`. `dbplyr` может использовать любое подключение, класс которого унаследован от `DBIConecction`.

Пример с использованием `RJDBC`:

```r
library(RJDBC)
drv <- JDBC(driverClass="com.vertica.jdbc.Driver", classPath="full\path\to\driver\vertica_jdbc_VERSION.jar")
con <- dbConnect(drv, "jdbc:vertica://host:5433/db", "username", "password")
tbl(con)
```

`jar` необходимо скачать с официального сайта. Там же можно найти и ODBC драйвер для Linux/Windows и использовать его с пакетом `odbc`.

Comment: Не получилось соединиться. Скачал драйвер jar с сайта. 'drv <- JDBC(driverClass="com.vertica.jdbc.Driver", classPath="C:\\Program Files\\Vertica Systems\\vertica-jdbc-10.0.0-0.jar")'> con <- dbConnect(drv, "jdbc:vertica://192.168.3.212:5450/db", "uidbadmin", "password")
Ошибка в .jcall(drv@jdrv, "Ljava/sql/Connection;", "connect", as.character(url)[1],  :
  java.sql.SQLException: [Vertica][VJDBC](100022) Unknown message type: . В вашем ответе учтено, что Vertika запущена в виртуальной машине?